# Vaadin - How to get a bean itself from the object id of the bean item in a bean item container

Tags: java, vaadin

I have set a ContainerDataSource for a ComboBox `this.comboBox.setContainerDataSource(container)`. This container is a BeanItemContainer.
Additionally, I created `TextFields` that are bound to certain attributes of the bean from the `BeanItemContainer`. For getting the selected data of the `ComboBox` I only can do `this.comboBox.getValue()`, which returns the object id of the selected bean. How can I use this information to get the actual selected bean itself? I need it to set the item data source of my text fields within the field group.

```
final BeanItemContainer<Person> personContainer = new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class);
for(int h = 0; h <= this.table.getSelectedItems().size() -1; h++) {
final Person person = this.table.getSelectedItems().get(h).getBean();    
personContainer.addBean(person);}
final Window win = new Window("Person", new PersonView(personContainer));
this.getUI().addWindow(win);
```

PersonView:

```
public PersonView(final BeanItemContainer<Person> personContainer) {
    super();
    this.initUI();

    this.comboBox.setContainerDataSource(personContainer);
    this.comboBox.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
    this.comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");

    }
private void comboBox_valueChange(final Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
    //this.fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(...);
}
```

Comment: With the ID you can lookup the item in the container...

Comment: @AndréSchild how do i do that?

Comment: Please show some more code, where you create the container

Comment: Here you are @AndréSchild

Comment: getValue() will return what you have defined. if you like you can return the bean itself as "object id".

Comment: Where is the combobox in your example code? i see a Table, not ComboBox.

Comment: Here is the full code. My question is what the commented statement has to look like in order to get the bean person that can be put in setItemDataSource. @d2k2

Comment: you dont need to write a for loop to fill the container with a collection. final BeanItemContainer<Person> personContainer = new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class, personCollection);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Vaadin 7.

Here is a solution to get the selected item from the ComboBox.:

```
        comboBox.addValueChangeListener( new ValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                Person person = (Person) comboBox.getValue();

                //do something with the selected value
                this.fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(person);              
            }
        });
```

Comment: The loop that you try to optimize away in the first part of your answer was primarily needed to build the personCollection, because V7 had no api to get a list of selected beans. And when you have a loop anyway, it doesn't really matter if they add single beans to the container within the loop, or create the container with a full collection of beans. +1 for the second part. Maybe replace your do-something comment with `this.fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(person);`